# Tensorflow DNN Regression is mostly ignoring categorical column

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am attempting to model the execution time of media file processing. I have 1.3M training records and .3M test records. I have four categorical columns (operation, server type, priority, and file type), two continuous columns (file size, media duration), and one target column (processing time, continuous).

I have adapted the Wide and Deep Tutorial code [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html) to use Regressors instead of Classifiers, and to output the predictions of the test evaluation. I have varied the width and depth of the hidden layers (e.g. [256, 128], [512, 256, 128, 64]). I changed from the default ProximalAdagradOptimizer to AdamOptimizer when I had divergence problems.

The Deep (DNN) and Wide and Deep (Linear Regression + DNN) seem to hit a loss plateau after 400 to 1000 steps, depending on the model specifics. The Wide (Linear Regression) seemed to plateau a couple of orders of magnitude higher. I have run these models up to 4000-10000 steps to try to get off the plateau.

Inspecting the predictions shows that the Deep and Wide and Deep results are relatively insensitive to my "operation" categorical column. I have tried increasing the dimensions of the categorical embedding columns (started with 8, but increased the "operation" value to 80), but that has not made much difference. The Wide results do show a sensitivity to "operation", but those results overall are worse.

The "operation" column is an integer in the range of 1-3000 with a about 300 distinct values.

I have done some measurements of my test data set and predictions. The RMS error of the predictions is on the order of the mean of the target. The mean of the predictions is about 70% of the mean of the actual values with similar ratios across the fivenum (Min, 1Q, Median, 3Q, Max). The ratio of prediction to target ranges from about 0.01 to 30. In short, the model is showing some promise, but it just does not seem to be finishing the job.

So hear are my questions:

- How can I coerce the model to pay more attention to the "operation" column? I would like to avoid using a hard weighting because I think the model should be able to learn the importance of this column. I fear I am just not presenting it properly to be incorporated.
- What should I look for in the model to determine the relevance learned for each column.
- Because my target varies over a large range (up to about 70,000) can or should I change the loss function to use a ratio of prediction to target instead of the raw difference? If so, how do I push that into functions like DNNLinearRegressor?

Can anyone suggest some next steps so I can get some more effective predictions out of this model?

UPDATE: I removed all categorical (sparse) feature columns from the model it trained to less than my previous lowest loss. It appears the categorical columns were not being used effectively, yet linear regressions in R suggested that these had strong correlations.